# Stopping the jQuery UI slider from moving past a given value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

On my page I have several sliders. They all need the same scale, but some of them go to 150, and some go to 200. I would like to set the max of them all to 200, but prevent some of them from moving passed 150. They are different $().slider() calls, so I'm simply interested in how to set the max of a slider to 200, but not allow any movement past 150...

I would think that this kind of behavior would be built-in, but apparently not?

FYI: I am using range: "min" for these sliders.

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/D9nAx/1/

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and/or scripts/css to your post so we can improve on top of what you have. In addition if you can create a fidde on jsFiddle.net that would also alow us to try out different solutions.

Comment: I'm sure you can use the slider events to control its behaviour.

Comment: link added: http://jsfiddle.net/D9nAx/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use slide event:

```
$( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    value: 60,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.value> 150)
            return false;
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
    }
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dvz8E

Comment: This is no good, sometimes if you move the mouse fast, it will stop on say 147. Needs `$(this).slider( "value" , 150 );` within the `>150` condition.

Comment: @Grantunwin i cant reproduce that behavior here... what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using FireFox 15.0.1. If you move the slider up quickly, that does it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Works fine in FireFox etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    value: 60,
    slide: slide
});
function slide(event, ui){
    var result = true;
    if (ui.value > 150){
        $(this).slider( "value" , 150 );
        result = false;
    }
    $( "#amount" ).val( $(this).slider( "value") );
    return result;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D9nAx/2/

Comment: This is almost perfect. The only issue is that if you slide up too fast, the slider won't max out. If I want the max to be 150, it'll stop at like 147. Is there any way to set the value of the slider to 150 if the .slider("value") is greater than 150...?

Comment: @Greg-J it works perfectly for me in all the latest browsers, what browser are you using?

Comment: I must have copied an older version as this is not the version you originally posted... Works great now. Thank you!